# Events in termcal that span more than a day

Tags: termcal

How can I mark those events using `termcal` that span more than one day?

For example, when I have a three-day final exam, the whole thing must be marked as Final Exam, and when I have a midterm break, the whole thing must be marked.

My current code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in, paperheight=8.5in, paperwidth=13in]{geometry}
\usepackage{termcal}
\pagenumbering{gobble}

\newcommand{\Class}{
\calday[Monday]{\classday}
\calday[Tuesday]{\classday}
\calday[Wednesday]{\classday}
\calday[Thursday]{\classday}
\calday[Friday]{\classday}
\calday[Saturday]{\noclassday} 
\calday[Sunday] {\noclassday}
}

\newcommand{\Holiday}[2]{
\options{#1}{\noclassday}
\caltext{#1}{#2}
}

\begin{document}
\paragraph*{Tedu's Schedule:}
\begin{center}
\begin{calendar}{5/1/2017}{53}
\setlength{\calboxdepth}{.3in}
\Class

\Holiday{5/1/2017}{Labor Day}
\Holiday{6/12/2017}{Independence Day}
\Holiday{6/26/2017}{Eid al-Fitr}
\Holiday{8/6/2017}{Cebu Province Charter Day}
\Holiday{8/21/2017}{Ninoy Aquino Day}
\Holiday{8/29/2017}{National Heroes Day}
\Holiday{11/1/2017}{All Saints' Day}
\Holiday{11/2/2017}{All Souls' Day}
\Holiday{11/30/2017}{Bonifacio Day}
\Holiday{12/24/2017}{Christmas Eve}
\Holiday{12/25/2017}{Christmas Day}
    % I want to merge it from here
\Holiday{12/26/2017}{}
\Holiday{12/27/2017}{}
\Holiday{12/28/2017}{}
\Holiday{12/29/2017}{}
    %to here
\Holiday{12/30/2017}{Rizal Day}
\Holiday{12/31/2017}{New Year's Eve}
\Holiday{1/1/2018}{New Year's Day}
\Holiday{2/25/2018}{EDSA Revolution Anniversary}

\caltext{5/31/2017}{End of Classes}
% By the way, how can I reset the number of days counter in here?
\caltext{8/1/2017}{Start of Classes}
\end{calendar}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Image of what I want to achieve (in Excel version):

[image]

Comment: Read the `termcal` documentation, in which I understand absolutely nothing.

Comment: Have a look at the `tikz calendar library` also.  Here's an example: http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/a-calender-for-doublesided-din-a4/ and here's the manual: http://mirrors.concertpass.com/tex-archive/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf

Comment: @TeokanDuranDemircan Many of your previous questions received answers which seems to answer the questions. Can you go back and accept the ones which solved your problems?

Comment: Do you have to use `termcal` or would you accept an alternative solution?

Comment: This is really not possible to do with `termcal` without major rewriting of the code.  As others have suggested, the TikZ calendar library is useful. There's also `pgfgantt` which might be adaptable to your needs.

Comment: I would accept a `pgfgantt` solution, if it is really impossible.

Comment: Providing some code would be helpful.